# View model works only in the theme layout issue

Tags: magento2, viewmodel

I've made this file:  `catalog_category_view.xml` in the `app/code/Namespace/Products/view/frontend/layout/` folder , with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Products\ViewModel\ListProductStock</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the `list.phtml` I have this:

```
$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
echo $viewModel->getTest();
```

and I am getting an error that it doesn't know about the `getTest()` method. But if I add my XML code for the view model in the `app/design/frontend/Magento/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`, it works!  Why? Why I cannot use my view model XML code in my custom module?

Also if I add this code: `<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" remove="true"/>` in the  `app/code/Namespace/Products/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`, it works. So not sure why the view model doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

My first impression is that in your module, you do not have the right xml path. I think you need to add the parent containers/blocks for it to work from the original catalog_category_view.xml (vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml). You should have something like this in your xml:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
         <referenceBlock name="category.products">
              <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                   <arguments>
                       <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Products\ViewModel\ListProductStock</argument>
                   </arguments>
         </referenceBlock>
     </referenceContainer>
```

Note that this should work only if you didnt change the layout structure in an other module.

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience you should change viewModel to view_model.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Products\ViewModel\ListProductStock</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thank you

Hiren Patel